# Adblock asks to hide Stack Overflow targeted messages

Tags: support, advertising

Opening Stack Overflow today, I've been greeted by the following AdBlock prompt:

[image: Targeted messages]

What would help Stack Overflow more, considering that I never click on Ads: to click on Yes or on No?

Comment: What do you think would help SO more? Impressions also pay.

Comment: I voted to close it as off topic. SO was the first page I opened, but the message appears on other sites as well, and clicking on Yes affects all sites.

Comment: Hmm, I don't recall that we have ever shown targeted messages to AdBlock users. No idea where this is coming from. Here's our ad blocker policy by the way: https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/26/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/

Comment: I know why this is happening. I'm going to re-open and answer this later today (hopefully), but it might be a while seeing as it's Thanksgiving here in the States.

Comment: For the record I received this message on several sites that haven't had it before. So either AdBlock has updated, or a common ad serving script has udpated.

Comment: If this is happening on more than just Stack sites, then I might not actually know why it’s happening.

Comment: Might be a little late, but don't pay attention to that message. I have even got that message on internal (company) sites that obviously don't have ads.

Comment: I've had this alert on Gmail as well. I would say Adblock might be reacting to false positives.